# Angular2 add image to file type from typescript

Tags: file, angular

I want to add a image to file type variable in angular2

I tried it like this

```
private file:File;

setImage(){
  this.file = "../assets/image/image.jpg"
}
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

```
private file:File;
this.file = "../assets/image/image.jpg"
```

I'm pretty sure the typescript compiler is telling you that you can't assign a `String` to a `File` type. That is why it's not working. In other words when you say that file is of type `File` then the typescript compiler is expecting a special kind of object, a `File` object. If you assign a `string` to it it will tell you it's wrong. When you write `:File` it isn't just a decoration, it tells typescript, hey I intend this to be a `File`, so if I assign anything else, make sure to scream at me.

So you could just do this, if you want a `string`:

```
private file:string;
this.file = "../assets/image/image.jpg"
```

Or  if you want a legal `File` object the doc on `File` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File
says this:

```
new File(
  Array parts,
  String filename, 
  BlobPropertyBag properties
);
```

So :

```
  file:File = new File(this.data , "filename");
```

Or if you want to be free of charges:

```
file:any;
```

On a side note, you should read the doc or the quickstart because if you don't understand typing, then there is no point in using typescript notations in the first place.